# What does $ \max\{f(x): x \in [0.1]\} =\{\max\{g(x) : x \in [0,1]\} $ mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What does the following statement mean?
$$ \max \{f(x): x\in [0.1]\}=\text{max}\{g(x) : x \in [0,1 ]\},$$

where $\text {max}$ is the [maximum-value function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13231/what-does-max-mean).

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628768/meaning-of-maxfx-in-a-given-range), I understand that the $ \max$ function, outputs the maximum value of a function in the given domain for all inputs in the said domain. Which makes no sense here.

For example, let $f(x)=x^2+2$ and $g(x)=3x+2$.

In the interval $[0,1]$, the maximum of $g(x)$ is $5,$ which leads to
$\max \{f(x) : x\in [0,1]\} =5$, which makes no sense whatsoever to me.

Comment: Where in those links they claim that $\max f=\max g$ holds for arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$? You should also improve your notation.

Comment: Please put backslashes  in front of your brackets in LaTeX, i.e. `\{\}`, so we can tell exactly what you're saying. The current rendering is un-readable, particularly the bit with $f$ in your last paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s dissect this notation:

$\{f(x): x\in [0.1]\}$ denotes the set of all $f(x)$ with $x∈[0,1]$, i.e., you go through all values in $[0,1]$, call them $x$, apply $f$ to them, and collect the outcomes in a set. Typically, this is denoted with a vertical bar (a.k.a. pipe) instead of a colon, i.e.:
$\{f(x) ~|~ x\in [0.1]\}$

To take your examples:

- For $f(x)=x^2+2$, the minimum value of $f$ within $[0,1]$ is $2$ (for $x=0$), the maximum value is $3$ (for $x=1$) and all values in between are assumed. Thus, $\{f(x): x\in [0.1]\}=[2,3]$.
- For $g(x)=3x+2$, the minimum value of $g$ within $[0,1]$ is $2$ (for $x=0$), the maximum value is $5$ (for $x=1$), and all values in between are assumed. Thus $\{g(x): x\in [0.1]\}=[2,5]$.

Once you understood this notation, the maximum is straightforward. If $S$ is any set of numbers, $\max S$ is the defined as the largest number from that set. For example $\max \{23,42,137\} = 137$ and $\max [0,7] = 7$.
To return to your examples:

- $\max \{f(x): x\in [0.1]\} = \max [2,3] = 3.$
- $\max \{g(x): x\in [0.1]\} = \max [2,5] = 5.$

So for your examples, we have:

$$\max \{f(x): x\in [0.1]\} = 3 \color{red}{≠} 5 = \max \{g(x): x\in [0.1]\},$$

and thus the initial statement is wrong. However, in another context imposing some constraints on $f$ and $g$, this statement can be correct.